When the index is the same, the database version is the same, but the same SQL statement has different execution plans on different hosts
I am currently using the version 8 of Dameng database. In SQL query sentences, I am dealing with a very large table. I have created the same unique index on this table in the development environment, but when I test the SQL query sentences in the development environment, they can use the index normally. However, When I use the EXPLAIN keyword to view the execution plan of a SQL statement, I find that, when I run the same SQL query sentences in the production environment, they cannot use the index.
The database version of both the development environment and the production environment is V8.Now I don't know what to try. I hope that the same SQL statement can get the same output in the production environment and the development environment.
WITH FilteredData AS (

    SELECT /*+ INDEX(T0403_DAY_DATA,T0403_DAY_DATA_IND) */
        c0007_point_id,
        c0403_flag,
        c0403_date,
        c0403_value
    FROM T0403_DAY_DATA
    WHERE c0403_date BETWEEN 1722441600 AND 1723046399
      AND c0403_flag IN (200, 201, 202)
),
BaseData AS (
    SELECT 
        c0007_point_id,
        c0403_date,
        MAX(CASE WHEN c0403_flag = 200 THEN c0403_value END) AS maxV,
        TO_CHAR(DATE '1970-01-01' + (MAX(CASE WHEN c0403_flag = 200 THEN c0403_date END) / 86400), 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') AS maxTime,
        MAX(CASE WHEN c0403_flag = 201 THEN c0403_value END) AS minV,
        TO_CHAR(DATE '1970-01-01' + (MAX(CASE WHEN c0403_flag = 201 THEN c0403_date END) / 86400), 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') AS minTime,
        MAX(CASE WHEN c0403_flag = 202 THEN c0403_value END) AS avgV
    FROM FilteredData
    GROUP BY c0007_point_id, c0403_date
),
FailRateData AS (
    SELECT 
        c0007_point_id,
        ROUND(
            CAST(
                COUNT(CASE WHEN c0403_flag = 202 AND (c0403_value > 10.7 OR c0403_value < 10) THEN 1 END) * 100.0 /
                NULLIF(COUNT(CASE WHEN c0403_flag = 202 THEN 1 END), 0) AS NUMERIC
            ), 4
        ) || '%' AS failRate
    FROM FilteredData
    WHERE c0403_flag = 202
    GROUP BY c0007_point_id
),
BaseInfo AS (
    SELECT 
        b.c0007_point_id,
        c.c1211_devid AS busId,
        c.c1211_devdesc AS busDesc,
        e.description AS stationDesc
    FROM T0007_POINT b
    JOIN T1211_DEVICE c ON b.c1211_devid = c.c1211_devid
    JOIN T0015_VOLTAGELEVEL d ON c.c0015_voltagelevelid = d.c0015_voltagelevelid
    JOIN (
        SELECT DISTINCT 
            t.substation AS suri,
            z.subctrlarea AS area,
            z.uri AS zone,
            a.description AS description
        FROM XOPENS.CIM_FEEDER t
        JOIN XOPENS.CIM_SUBSTATION a ON t.substation = a.uri
        JOIN XOPENS.CIM_ZONE z ON t.zone = z.uri
    ) e ON d.c0003_station_no = TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR(e.suri, INSTR(e.suri, '-') + 1))
    WHERE b.c1220_meastypeid = 206
      AND c.c1216_devtype = 'BS'
      AND d.c0015_voltagelevel = '10kV'
)
SELECT 
    n.stationDesc,
    n.busDesc,
    n.busId,
    b.maxV AS maxHis,
    b.maxTime AS maxTimeHis,
    b.minV AS minHis,
    b.minTime AS minTimeHis,
    b.avgV AS avgHis,
    f.failRate AS volFailRateHis
FROM BaseInfo n 
JOIN BaseData b ON n.c0007_point_id = b.c0007_point_id 
JOIN FailRateData f ON b.c0007_point_id = f.c0007_point_id
ORDER BY n.stationDesc, n.busDesc;

The execution plan in production environment is following.
1   #NSET2: [3520786, 22668, 882] 
2     #PRJT2: [3520786, 22668, 882]; exp_num(9), is_atom(FALSE) 
3       #SORT3: [3520786, 22668, 882]; key_num(2), partition_key_num(0), is_distinct(FALSE), top_flag(0), is_adaptive(0)
4         #HASH2 INNER JOIN: [3520779, 22668, 882];  KEY_NUM(2); KEY(F.C0007_POINT_ID=B.C0007_POINT_ID AND N.C0007_POINT_ID=B.C0007_POINT_ID) KEY_NULL_EQU(0, 0)
5           #SLCT2: [1255372, 15112, 762]; F.C0007_POINT_ID = N.C0007_POINT_ID
6             #NEST LOOP INNER JOIN2: [1255372, 15112, 762]; [with var]
7               #PRJT2: [43, 17778, 642]; exp_num(4), is_atom(FALSE) 
8                 #HASH2 INNER JOIN: [43, 17778, 642];  KEY_NUM(1); KEY(D.C0003_STATION_NO=exp11) KEY_NULL_EQU(0)
9                   #HASH2 INNER JOIN: [22, 1670, 354]; LKEY_UNIQUE KEY_NUM(1); KEY(C.C1211_DEVID=B.C1211_DEVID) KEY_NULL_EQU(0)
10                    #HASH2 INNER JOIN: [19, 1848, 264]; LKEY_UNIQUE KEY_NUM(1); KEY(D.C0015_VOLTAGELEVELID=C.C0015_VOLTAGELEVELID) KEY_NULL_EQU(0)
11                      #SLCT2: [1, 253, 108]; D.C0015_VOLTAGELEVEL = '10kV'
12                        #CSCN2: [1, 1689, 108]; INDEX34393935(T0015_VOLTAGELEVEL as D); btr_scan(1)
13                      #BLKUP2: [15, 13381, 156]; T1211_DEVICE_I3(C)
14                        #SSEK2: [15, 13381, 156]; scan_type(ASC), T1211_DEVICE_I3(T1211_DEVICE as C), scan_range['BS','BS']
15                    #SSEK2: [1, 9640, 90]; scan_type(ASC), IDX_T0007_MEASTYPEID_ID(T0007_POINT as B), scan_range[(exp_cast(206),min,min),(exp_cast(206),max,max))
16                  #PRJT2: [19, 3054, 288]; exp_num(2), is_atom(FALSE) 
17                    #DISTINCT: [19, 3054, 288]
18                      #HASH2 INNER JOIN: [18, 3054, 288];  KEY_NUM(1); KEY(T.SUBSTATION=A.URI) KEY_NULL_EQU(0)
19                        #HASH2 INNER JOIN: [1, 2946, 192];  KEY_NUM(1); KEY(Z.URI=T.ZONE) KEY_NULL_EQU(0)
20                          #PARALLEL: [1, 164, 96]; scan_type(FULL), key_num(0, 0, 0), simple(0)
21                            #CSCN2: [1, 164, 96]; INDEX33714966(CIM_ZONE as Z); btr_scan(1)
22                          #PARALLEL: [1, 2870, 96]; scan_type(FULL), key_num(0, 0, 0), simple(0)
23                            #CSCN2: [1, 2870, 96]; INDEX33714976(CIM_FEEDER as T); btr_scan(1)
24                        #PARALLEL: [9, 76610, 96]; scan_type(FULL), key_num(0, 0, 0), simple(0)
25                          #CSCN2: [9, 76610, 96]; INDEX33714764(CIM_SUBSTATION as A); btr_scan(1)
26              #PRJT2: [64, 1419, 120]; exp_num(2), is_atom(FALSE) 
27                #SAGR2: [64, 1419, 120]; grp_num(1), sfun_num(2), distinct_flag[0,0]; slave_empty(0) keys(DMTEMPVIEW_901191724.TMPCOL0) 
28                  #PRJT2: [53, 141990, 120]; exp_num(3), is_atom(FALSE) 
29                    #PRJT2: [53, 141990, 120]; exp_num(3), is_atom(FALSE) 
30                      #PARALLEL: [53, 141990, 120]; scan_type(GE_LE), key_num(0, 1, 1), simple(0)
31                        #BLKUP2: [53, 47330, 120]; T0403_DAY_DATA_IND(T0403_DAY_DATA)
32                          #SSEK2: [53, 47330, 120]; scan_type(ASC), T0403_DAY_DATA_IND(T0403_DAY_DATA), scan_range[(var3,exp_cast(202),exp_cast(1722441600)),(var3,exp_cast(202),exp_cast(1723046399))]
33          #PRJT2: [2265388, 170388, 120]; exp_num(6), is_atom(FALSE) 
34            #HAGR2: [2265388, 170388, 120]; grp_num(2), sfun_num(5), distinct_flag[0,0,0,0,0]; slave_empty(0) keys(DMTEMPVIEW_901191723.TMPCOL0, DMTEMPVIEW_901191723.TMPCOL1) 
35              #PRJT2: [2261787, 17038818, 120]; exp_num(7), is_atom(FALSE) 
36                #PRJT2: [2261787, 17038818, 120]; exp_num(4), is_atom(FALSE) 
37                  #PARALLEL: [2261787, 17038818, 120]; scan_type(GE_LE), key_num(0, 1, 1), simple(0)
38                    #HASH RIGHT SEMI JOIN2: [2261787, 17038818, 120]; n_keys(1) KEY(DMTEMPVIEW_901191759.colname=T0403_DAY_DATA.C0403_FLAG) KEY_NULL_EQU(0)
39                      #CONST VALUE LIST: [1, 3, 30]; row_num(3), col_num(1)
40                      #SLCT2: [2261787, 2019415547, 120]; [(T0403_DAY_DATA.C0403_DATE >= var15 AND T0403_DAY_DATA.C0403_DATE <= var16)]
41                        #BLKUP2: [6785363, 6058246641, 120]; T0403_DAY_DATA_IND(T0403_DAY_DATA)
42                          #SSCN: [6785363, 6058246641, 120]; T0403_DAY_DATA_IND(T0403_DAY_DATA); btr_scan(1)

The execution plan in development environment is following.
1   #NSET2: [25, 3, 882] 
2     #PRJT2: [25, 3, 882]; exp_num(9), is_atom(FALSE) 
3       #SORT3: [25, 3, 882]; key_num(2), is_distinct(FALSE), top_flag(0), is_adaptive(0)
4         #SLCT2: [25, 3, 882]; (B.C0007_POINT_ID = F.C0007_POINT_ID AND N.C0007_POINT_ID = B.C0007_POINT_ID)
5           #NEST LOOP INNER JOIN2: [25, 3, 882]; [with var]
6             #SLCT2: [17, 1, 762]; F.C0007_POINT_ID = N.C0007_POINT_ID
7               #NEST LOOP INNER JOIN2: [17, 1, 762]; [with var]
8                 #PRJT2: [12, 1, 642]; exp_num(4), is_atom(FALSE) 
9                   #SLCT2: [12, 1, 642]; D.C0003_STATION_NO = exp11
10                    #NEST LOOP INNER JOIN2: [12, 1, 642]; [with var]
11                      #HASH2 INNER JOIN: [4, 1, 354];  KEY_NUM(1); KEY((C.C1211_DEVID=B.C1211_DEVID))
12                        #SLCT2: [0, 14, 264]; C.C1216_DEVTYPE = 'BS'
13                          #HASH2 INNER JOIN: [0, 14, 264]; LKEY_UNIQUE KEY_NUM(1); KEY((D.C0015_VOLTAGELEVELID=C.C0015_VOLTAGELEVELID))
14                            #SLCT2: [0, 14, 264]; C.C1216_DEVTYPE = 'BS'
15                              #NEST LOOP INDEX JOIN2: [0, 14, 264] 
16                                #ACTRL: [0, 14, 264];
17                                  #SLCT2: [0, 7, 108]; D.C0015_VOLTAGELEVEL = '10kV'
18                                    #CSCN2: [0, 299, 108]; INDEX33556139(T0015_VOLTAGELEVEL as D)
19                                #BLKUP2: [0, 2, 0]; C1211_DEVTYPE(C)
20                                  #SSEK2: [0, 2, 0]; scan_type(ASC), C1211_DEVTYPE(T1211_DEVICE as C), scan_range[D.C0015_VOLTAGELEVELID,D.C0015_VOLTAGELEVELID]
21                            #CSCN2: [35, 256500, 156]; INDEX33556635(T1211_DEVICE as C)
22                        #SSEK2: [1, 10721, 90]; scan_type(ASC), INDEX_T0007_MEASTYPEID_ID(T0007_POINT as B), scan_range[(exp_cast(206),min,min),(exp_cast(206),max,max))
23                      #PRJT2: [4, 1, 288]; exp_num(2), is_atom(FALSE) 
24                        #DISTINCT: [4, 1, 288]
25                          #HASH2 INNER JOIN: [3, 59, 288];  KEY_NUM(1); KEY((T.ZONE=Z.URI))
26                            #HASH2 INNER JOIN: [2, 54, 192];  KEY_NUM(1); KEY((T.SUBSTATION=A.URI))
27                              #NEST LOOP INDEX JOIN2: [2, 54, 192] 
28                                #ACTRL: [2, 54, 192];
29                                  #PARALLEL: [0, 27, 96]; scan_type(FULL), key_num(0, 0, 0) 
30                                    #SLCT2: [0, 27, 96]; var9 = exp11
31                                      #CSCN2: [0, 1094, 96]; INDEX33558033(CIM_FEEDER as T)
32                                #PARALLEL: [1, 2, 0]; scan_type(FULL), key_num(0, 0, 0) 
33                                  #CSEK2: [1, 2, 0]; scan_type(ASC), INDEX33557604(CIM_SUBSTATION as A), scan_range[(T.SUBSTATION,min),(T.SUBSTATION,max))
34                              #PARALLEL: [5, 43432, 96]; scan_type(FULL), key_num(0, 0, 0) 
35                                #CSCN2: [5, 43432, 96]; INDEX33557604(CIM_SUBSTATION as A)
36                            #PARALLEL: [0, 110, 96]; scan_type(FULL), key_num(0, 0, 0) 
37                              #CSCN2: [0, 110, 96]; INDEX33558019(CIM_ZONE as Z)
38                #PRJT2: [1, 1, 120]; exp_num(2), is_atom(FALSE) 
39                  #SAGR2: [1, 1, 120]; grp_num(1), sfun_num(2) slave_empty(0) keys(DMTEMPVIEW_20860601.TMPCOL0) 
40                    #SORT3: [1, 1, 120]; key_num(1), is_distinct(FALSE), top_flag(0), is_adaptive(1)
41                      #PRJT2: [0, 10, 120]; exp_num(3), is_atom(FALSE) 
42                        #PRJT2: [0, 10, 120]; exp_num(2), is_atom(FALSE) 
43                          #PARALLEL: [0, 10, 120]; scan_type(GE_LE), key_num(0, 1, 1) 
44                            #HASH RIGHT SEMI JOIN2: [0, 10, 120]; n_keys(1)   KEY((DMTEMPVIEW_20860635.colname=exp_cast(202)))
45                              #CONST VALUE LIST: [0, 3, 30]; row_num(3), col_num(1), 
46                              #BLKUP2: [2, 133, 120]; T0403_DAY_DATA_IND(T0403_DAY_DATA)
47                                #SSEK2: [2, 133, 120]; scan_type(ASC), T0403_DAY_DATA_IND(T0403_DAY_DATA), scan_range[(var8,exp_cast(202),exp_cast(1722441600)),(var8,exp_cast(202),exp_cast(1723046399))]
48            #PRJT2: [3, 1, 120]; exp_num(6), is_atom(FALSE) 
49              #HAGR2: [3, 1, 120]; grp_num(2), sfun_num(5); slave_empty(0) keys(DMTEMPVIEW_20860600.TMPCOL0, DMTEMPVIEW_20860600.TMPCOL1) 
50                #PRJT2: [2, 10, 120]; exp_num(7), is_atom(FALSE) 
51                  #PRJT2: [2, 10, 120]; exp_num(4), is_atom(FALSE) 
52                    #SLCT2: [2, 10, 120]; T0403_DAY_DATA.C0007_POINT_ID = var7
53                      #NEST LOOP INDEX JOIN2: [2, 10, 120] 
54                        #CONST VALUE LIST: [0, 3, 0]; row_num(3), col_num(1), 
55                        #PARALLEL: [2, 44, 120]; scan_type(GE_LE), key_num(0, 1, 1) 
56                          #BLKUP2: [8, 133, 120]; T0403_DAY_DATA_IND(T0403_DAY_DATA)
57                            #SSEK2: [8, 133, 120]; scan_type(ASC), T0403_DAY_DATA_IND(T0403_DAY_DATA), scan_range[(var6,DMTEMPVIEW_20860617.colname,exp_cast(1722441600)),(var6,DMTEMPVIEW_20860617.colname,exp_cast(1723046399))]


Did you gather statistics on both systems?

Yes, I collected the execution plan results for the development environment and the production environment. The data volume of a large table involved in the development environment is in the millions, and the data volume of the large table in the production environment is in the billions.

You have now answered yourself. Different data volumes, different statistics.

Oracle has for decades now used an intelligent optimizer that tries to make decisions based on numerous factors that are predictive of cardinality (# of rows expected from a table or a join or a sort, etc..). It isn't a static list of rules anymore. Therefore, a prod database and a dev database even with the same structure have differences that influence the optimizer in each environment in different ways. You simply cannot expect the same plan in both environments with any degree of consistency.

You've tagged this question with the oracle-database tag.  Your query plan does not look like an Oracle query plan.  And you say that you are using something called "Dameng database".  So my guess is that you are not using Oracle and that tag needs to be removed.

The syntax of the Dameng database I am using is basically the same as that of the Oracle database. However, there is no entry for the Dameng database here, so I have to use the Oracle database entry instead of the Dameng database entry.

Computing a query plan is a very complex process that relies on systemic. There is many conditions to obtain a query plan that will be exactly the same on two similar machines...
The most important of them are:

the resources of the different machines in terms of hardware that must be strictly identical (CPU,
RAM, disk organisation and speed...)
the fact that statistics is generally created/updated by a random sample instaed of a FULLSCAN

Other conditions can increase the differences like:

the usage of a VM (unstable resources)
the defragmentation of indexes and tables (that increase or decrease the global volume of data to be scrutinized

Are you sure that thoses things are strictly the same ?

Well, these are not sure.To be precise, I don't expect to get exactly the same execution plan, but I hope to achieve the same effect in some key areas, such as using secondary indexes and performing table retrieval operations instead of full table scans when querying.

I tested this SQL statement again in another database with a different amount of data, and the execution plan showed that the secondary index could be used to retrieve the table. Well, maybe the problem here is that the full table scan is caused by the large amount of data. Although I don’t know how to deal with it, it is obvious that it seems that it is not efficient to achieve similar queries.
